google-api-node No overload matches this call
Hi have the inline piece of code:
    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'];
// Load the service account key from file

const auth:GoogleAuth<JSONClient> = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes: SCOPES,
});

var allValidUsers: string[] = [];

const authClient = await auth.getClient();

if (authClient instanceof google.auth.JWT) {
    authClient.subject = DELEGATED_USER;
}
// vscode complains about this although this is the code from the library itself: 
// https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/a865e81539b315d3b321650663ba0b2555b1e5a1/samples/directory_v1/group-email-delete.js#L29C1-L33C6
const service = google.admin({ version: 'directory_v1', auth: authClient });

VSCode is complaining about the last line:

No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
error.
Type '"directory_v1"' is not assignable to type '"reports_v1"'.
Type 'JSONClient | Compute' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth | OAuth2Client |
undefined'.
Type 'ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth |
OAuth2Client | undefined'.
Type 'ExternalAccountAuthorizedUserClient' is missing the following properties from type 'OAuth2Client': certificateCache,
certificateExpiry, certificateCacheFormat, refreshTokenPromises, and
26 more.

I don't really now what else I need to do, the code is per examples, I need to have the authClient there since I'm calling the Admin SDK API with Domain Wide Delegation, which requires a servive account key and a delegation account.
I've been readin the docs, but cannot really find how to quiet VS Code without ignoring the message.
Any ideas?
